# Arrays of pointers to strings - C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have a problem that I really can't understand. I'm a newbie C programmer, and I have a program that roughly goes like this:

```
void filetostr(FILE *, char *s[]);
void strtofile(char *s[], FILE *);
void XORstr(char *, int);
void XORtext(char *s[], int);
void printext(char *s[]);

int main(int args, char *argv[]) {

    char *s[MAXLENGTH];
    char ln[MAXLENGTH];

    FILE *input, *xorred, *rexorred, *out;

    input = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    filetostr(input, s);
    fclose(input);

    printext(s);

    XORtext(s, KEY);        
}

void filetostr(FILE *fp, char *s[]) {
    char ln[MAXLENGTH];
    char *p;
    int i = 0;

    while (fgets(ln, MAXLINE, fp)) {
        p = (char *) malloc(strlen(ln) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(p, ln);
        s[i++] = p;
    }
}

void printext(char *s[]) {
    while (*s) {
        printf("%s", *s);
        s++;
    }
}

void XORstr(char *s, int key) {
    int c;
    while (c = *s)
        *s++ = key ^ c;
}

void XORtext(char *txt[], int key) {
    while (*txt) {
        XORstr(*txt, key);
        txt++;
    }
}
```

And I have two two problems:

- first, when I build the array of pointers to strings with `filetostr`, I get it to work but two lines in the middle of the text are repeated (there are two references to them in the array, so with `printext` they get printed twice). How is that possible? Is there a wrong call to malloc?
- second, when I try to XOR the lines I just mentioned, they get XORred only once, so I end up with a XORred line and a normal one for each duplicate line.

Comment: Also,don't forget to check 1) return-value from `malloc()` function. `if(p == NULL) { /* no memory */ exit(1); }` and 2) if there is enough space to store `p` in `s` array; before of `s[i++] = p;` : `if(i >= MAXLENGTH) { /* no space to hold p in s */ }` It may crash your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 p = (char *) malloc((strlen(ln) + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

instead of

```
 p = (char *) malloc(strlen(ln) * sizeof(char));
```

BTW, you can change

```
p = (char *) malloc((strlen(ln)+1) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(p, ln);
s[i++] = p;
```

by

```
s[i++] = strdup(ln)
```

It's the same

Comment: But isn't `strdup()` POSIX?

Comment: This way where do I move along the array? Previously I did it with `i++`... Maybe I have to add `s[i++] = p;` after the `strdup` function?

Comment: sorry I make a mistake in my answer it should be `s[i++] = strdup(ln)`. I will update the answer

Answer (score 1):

The `malloc` in `filetostr` isn't quite right.  It should be

```
p = malloc(strlen(ln) + 1);
```

You need to allocate space for the terminating null character, don't need to cast the return and can rely on `sizeof(char)` being 1